# disabling Position Independent Code & ASLR with Qt5 on Linux?

Tags: gdb, debian, qt5, x86-64, aslr

On Linux [Debian](https://debian.org/)/Sid/x86-64 for the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) GPLv3+ project using Qt5 (5.12.5 as packaged by Debian), I prefer to disable [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to ease debugging (and facilitate [GDB watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)). FWIW, that project is generating C++ code on the fly at runtime, compiling it into a [shared library](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), and is [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ing the obtained plugins. So using `gdb`  is definitely useful.

So with RefPerSys [git commit `dae216918be51c`... on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/commit/dae216918be51c0c025d8d57369d186db08e4923) compiled by `g++` 9.3.0 from Debian, using `make RPS_BUILD_CODGENFLAGS=` (or edit the [`Makefile`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/Makefile#L53) to undefine it) after both a `make clean` and then a `make fullclean` I am getting the following reproducible compiler error:

```
ccache g++ -std=gnu++17 -Og -g3  -Wall -Wextra -I .  -I /usr/local/include  -I /usr/include -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -DRPS_GITID=\"dae216918be51c0c025d8d57369d186db08e4923+\"   -c -c -o refpersys.hh.gch-tmp refpersys.hh
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qnamespace.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QObject:1,
                 from refpersys.hh:100:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1187:4: error: #error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
 1187 | #  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\
      |    ^~~~~
```

As the error message says, **it is related to Qt5 having been built with `-reduce-relocations`** by Debian folks. Since then *You must build your code with position independent code*

#### Is it just a matter of recompiling Qt5 from its source code, or is it more subtle than that?

More broadly:

### how to use GDB watchpoints on Qt5 code compiled on Debian/Sid?

Of course I want hardware watchpoints. Typically printing some pointer under `gdb` - which would give for example `0x7fafb071b8`  then `watch *(int*) 0x7fafb071b8`  inside `gdb`

[QT bug 84159](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-84159) is motivated and related to the question above. Compiling Qt from source is not that simple....

I just added a `--no-aslr`  program option (using [personality(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) hints from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/507954/64680) to disable programmatically ASLR). That option sometimes run [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) on the current process. I am observing widely different maps from one run to the next one.

PS. To reproduce the bug, after a successful `make` *without* setting `RPS_BUILD_CODGENFLAGS=` run twice `./refpersys --no-aslr -dGUI --display=object`. The two `_refpersys*Pmap*.tmp` files (output of `pmap`) are widely different. I expected them to be similar. For coding details in may 2020, please `grep`  for the `rps_disable_aslr` variable in the C++ source code, files  [`refpersys.hh`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/refpersys.hh#L203),  [`appli_qrps.cc`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/appli_qrps.cc#L614), and mostly [`main_rps.cc`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/main_rps.cc#L332) ....

NB: Same error appears on [Mageia](https://www.mageia.org/en) 7.1 installed on [my laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564066/50557).
So in [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) we are switching to [FLTK](https://fltk.org/).

Comment: There's [anecdotal evidence](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1700435#c5) that building Qt from source with `-no-reduce-relocations` will produce a library that can be linked with a non-PIC object file, at least for a small test case.